# Additional whitespace appearing at bottom of auto-resizing textarea element

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I have a textarea which I have added an `onChange` listener to in order to update the field's height whenever a new line is required (or if a line is no longer required). The issue I'm having is that, when the cursor approaches the end of the (current) final line of the textarea, additional whitespace is created which does not actually "exist" (i.e. it consists of no characters - sort of an "empty line").

My description probably isn't sufficient to explain the issue I'm having, but the same effect can be observed in the JSFiddle below (I'm using an identical implementation for my own form):

https://jsfiddle.net/d9fqaest/

As you can see, when the end of the first line is reached, a new line is added without issue:

[image]

But when the end of the second line (or any following lines) is reached, a new "empty" line is added too soon (with any following lines requiring fewer and fewer characters before adding the erroneous line):

[image]

I suspect the issue lies somewhere in the way the row count is calculated:

```
handleChange(e) {
    const oldRows = e.target.rows;
    e.target.rows = 1;
    const newRows = ~~(e.target.scrollHeight/lineHeight);

    if (newRows === oldRows) {
        e.target.rows = newRows;
    }

    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value,
        rows: newRows
    });
}
```

I've tried a few different flows of logic here, including simply setting the element's `height` to its `scrollHeight`, but I haven't been able to produce the desired behaviour (the aforementioned approach somewhat worked, but I was unable to figure out how to remove lines as text was deleted). I'm aware of several external libraries which would solve this problem, but I'd like to avoid using those if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue. Using Chrome 74 in Mac. Which browser and OS you are using??

Comment: @DaniVijay It's present for me in Chrome 74, Edge 44 and Firefox 66 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out all that was needed was `overflow-y: hidden` on the textarea to prevent the scrollbar from being included in the height calculation. Simple fix!